# adb loses connection after 10-15 minutes on macOS Sierra

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, macos-sierra

Ever since updating my Macbook Pro 2015 from El Capitan to Sierra I'm experiencing connection loses (via USB-cables) to my android devices after around 15 minutes. When I unplug the device it takes several tries to recognize the device again. Sometimes after the 10th times of unplugging.

I've experienced this with the following devices:

- Motorola Moto G (Android 5)
- Samsung Galaxy S7 (Android 6)
- LG G5 (Android 7)

I'm running Android Studio on version 2.2.3 with Android SDK Tools 25.2.5 and Android SDK Platform Tools 25.0.3

I've found several other sources online which say it should be fixed with Platform Tools 24.0.4 but for me it isn't.

Other sources suggested it is due to bad ports on the Macbook Pro, however I did not have problems on El Capitan so I would exclude this cause. I've tried all ports on my Macbook and it makes no difference.

The devices are connected via MTP.

Comment: Having the same problem. I tried all the steps suggested to fix however no luck

Comment: For now I just switched to adb wireless debugging. It's a little more time to setup, but way less then unplugging every 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?